# Error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, stringify

I have a problem with my application. Anyone can help me?

**Error:
Converting circular structure to JSON**

My Service to create items and save on localstorage:

```js
  addItem(item: Item): void {
    this.itens.unshift(item);
    let itens;
    if (localStorage.getItem('itens') == null){
      itens = [];
      itens.unshift(itens);
      localStorage.setItem('itens', JSON.stringify(itens));
    } else {
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itens'));
      itens.unshift(itens);
      localStorage.setItem('itens', JSON.stringify(itens));
    }
  }
```

And my `component.ts`:

```js
  addItem(): void  {
    this.itemAdicionado.emit({
      nome: this.nome,
      unidade: this.unidade,
      quantidade: this.quantidade,
      preco: this.preco,
      perecivel: true,
      validade: this.validade,
      fabricacao: this.fabricacao,
    });

    this.nome = '';
    this.unidade ;
    this.quantidade ;
    this.preco;
    this.validade;
    this.fabricacao;

    console.log(this.nome, this.unidade, this.quantidade, this.preco, this.validade, this.fabricacao);
  }
```

Comment: If you add more details about error like complete stack trace that will be helpful to answer your question..

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer but i'm begginer, if  help and you want see the project has be available on my github https://github.com/oliveirawesley/angular6-studies , thank you so much.

Comment: @WesleyOliveira - Welcome to stack overflow. Kindly put a detailed description of the error along with the code. It is hard to understand what problem you are facing.

Comment: @AnkitSharma 
Thank you so much : D
This is an application for registering items and saving this data in the localstorage, however after filling in all the form data and submitting, it does not save in the localstorage appearing the error in the console:
ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Comment: @WesleyOliveira - Can you create this application on stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Please [edit] your question, so that it contains a [mcve] along with the verbatim error message you get. Don't paraphrase, don't replace observations with interpretations and make sure the code is stripped of redundant stuff but still complete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an Angular error. It's a JavaScript runtime error thrown by the `JSON.stringify` function. The error tells you that `itens` contains a circular object reference. This is OK while you run the application, but when stringifying it causes a problem: the JSON generated would become infinitely long.

As Kevin Koelzer indicated in his answer. The problem is that you wrote `itens.unshift(itens);`. Basically this adds the array of items to the array of items, thus creating a circular reference. Therefore, writing `itens.unshift(item);` instead solves your problem and is probably what you intended to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
itens.unshift(itens);
```

could this be:

```
itens.unshift(iten);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20705722)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the feedback.